# Xcode environment variables for sub projects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, environment-variables

My current Xcode iOS project uses a number of static libraries. The different code modules in the static libraries have various levels of debug that I can switch on/off with #defines from within that module.

What I want to do is have all the debug default to off in the library then set the debug level from the parent project. I want to do this so any proj that uses the lib has to explicitly turn on debug.

So MainProj uses myLib1 and myLib2 etc. Within myLib1 is a module called fooModule. fooModule has debug code such as:

```
#if FOOMODULE_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
//debug code, console logs etc
#endif
```

I want to be able to define FOOMODULE_DEBUG_LEVEL in the parent project so the library picks it up at build time and compiles appropriately.

I have tried:

```
#define FOOMODULE_DEBUG_LEVEL 1
```

in the main project .pch
and I have tried adding FOOMODULE_DEBUG_LEVEL as a user defined environment variable with a value of 1. Neither of which were picked up by the sub project lib.

Is there a way of doing this or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

you accomplish this without multiple definitions by creating xcconfig files and then referencing or `#include`-ing them throughout your projects. so, you could apply Mattias' suggestion and then define the preprocessor defs in the xcconfig. then you have one file to change (and a full rebuild if you require these defs in the pch file, which there are separate settings for).

xcode also lets you assign separate xcconfigs per build configuration.

Comment: I added AppDebug.xcconfig to my project and in the project info page set my debug and release builds to be 'based' on AppDebug.xcconfig. Then in AppDebug.xcconfig added DEBUG_VARIABLE = 1. #if defined (DEBUG_VARIABLE) NSLog(@"this is a test");#endif fails to print anything. I must be missing something as to how xcconfig files work.

Comment: add it as a preprocessor definition: `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG_VARIABLE=1 $(inherited)`

Answer (score 0):

I would edit the schema and add a pre-build shell script to set the proper variables.
When you add a script you can establish from which target you are getting the definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe add a define using the "Preprocessor macros" build setting to the targets and or debug/release build configurations where you want to enable debug.

In your case you would double click on on the value column and then click "+" to add a new macro. The marco would be "FOOMODULE_DEBUG_LEVEL=1" which should result in `-DFOOMODULE_DEBUG_LEVEL=1` to the compiler.

Comment: Hi Mattias,Adding preprocessor macros doesn't seem to affect the build of the sub projects (i.e. static libs) that I have included in the main project

Comment: This isn't visible in static library. Can you please tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: Your building a static library or your linking with an already built static library? -D macros are only used at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

Solution

1) Target > Build Settings > Preprocessor macros. Set environment variable as preprocessor def for target (seems that must be target rather than project), e.g. DEBUG_VARIABLE=1

2) Project > Build phases > Add build phase. Then in the Run Script export the variable:
export DEBUG_VARIABLE

All sub projects now pick up this environment variable.

I think the ideal would be to also use Justin's suggestion of having an .xcconfig file with all the preprocessor macros defined in one place to make it easy to edit them. For the life of me I can't make this work. If I put this in the .xcconfig file:
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG_VARIABLE=1 $(inherited)
Then base the debug and/or release build on this configuration the DEBUG_VARIABLE environment variable never gets set.

Comment: Update: If I create a new project then add an .xcconfig file as described above the environment variable is set and #ifdefs work in the code on this variable. If I follow exactly the same procedure in the project I am working on it doesn't work. I guess there must be something peculiar with the project settings of my main project...no idea what though!

Comment: I think I had a setting in the target overriding the project setting. I deleted all the preprocessor macros in the build and now the .xcconfig file seems to work. Changes are not always picked up in the build unless I do a clean. Must remember to do this!

Comment: Tried to use this advice, however I don't have any build phases on project level. Adding any run scripts to the target level (where I have build phases) won't help, since they're not run before the sub projects are being built.

Comment: there's no build phase in projec settings. it is in target settings.